# An ArrayList of Arrays of Strings

Tags: java

```
String s[] = {"a,b,c", "d,e,f"};
```

I'd like to split each string up into arrays of subitems.  So that I end up with something like this is pseudocode: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

```
String arr[] = {"a,b,c", "d,e,f"};
List<String[]> groups = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String s : arr) {
    groups.add(s.split(","));
}
```

Was hoping the above would do the trick, but I think I am misunderstanding my List declaration?

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>();` is a list of strings, not arrays. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: `new ArrayList<String[]>()`, or better yet `new ArrayList<>()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a small typo in you code. Use the below code.

```
        String arr[] = {"a,b,c", "d,e,f"};
        List<String[]> groups = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        for(String s : arr) {
            groups.add(s.split(","));
        }
```